# ng-click directive is not calling the entire function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to move a marker inside the google maps map. I have a function to move them and they are working fine. For testing, I had invoked them inside the script and they are working as expected.

But when I am trying to call the function within the ng-click directive, the function is getting called but the entire code is not being executed.

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="x()">Click here to move the marker</md-button>
```

Method:

```
$scope.x = function ()
      {
        console.log('a');
          $scope.marker = {
          id: 6,
          coords: {latitude:-28.226349,longitude:-52.381581}
          };
      }
```

Inside the console the 'a' is getting printed, but the marker doesn't move to latitude: -28.226349, longitude: -52.381581.

If I call the function inside the script like this:

```
$scope.x = function ()
      {
        console.log('a');
          $scope.marker = {
          id: 6,
          coords: {latitude:-28.226349,longitude:-52.381581}
          };
      }

      $scope.x();
```

When the page is loaded, the marker is at latitude: -28.226349, longitude: -52.381581.

Entire HTML:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="x()">Click here to move the marker</md-button>
<div id="map" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'  options="map.options">

<ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="6"></ui-gmap-marker>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: Can you console.log the $scope.marker to check whether the coords value is getting updated or not? It can be an issue with data binding as well, where the coords' value is getting updated but getting properly binded to the screen.

Comment: I've tried it right now and surprisingly the coordinates update... Another creepy thing that I noticed now is that the 'a' (from the console.log) shows up twice when I call it on the script, and just one time when I call it via ng-click, I don't know if this is related... Both ways (when I call the function via ng-click and on the script) the coordinates update.

Comment: So is your issue resoved now? Are the co-ordinates getting updated correctly are you still facing the binding issue?

Comment: No sorry. My problem is that the marker doesn't move, the coordinates are updating, I don't know why, but it still doesn't move.

Comment: Looks like it's a binding problem (the variable change is not getting binded to the HTML). Can you share some more code as to how you are binding the coords in HTML?

Comment: I edited the body of the question and put all the html that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqyKYr?editors=1010).

It is working as expected. I think the issue is with your idkey. Make the idkey dynamic and bind it to the ID of the marker object.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="gMap">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="x()">Marker</md-button>
  <ui-gmap-google-map 
    center='map.center' 
    zoom='map.zoom' aria-label="Google map">

    <ui-gmap-marker
      coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
      <ui-gmap-window>
        <div>{{marker.window.title}}</div>
      </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>

  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller("gMap", function($scope) {
  $scope.x = function() {
    console.log('a');
    $scope.marker = {
    id: 6,
    "coords": {
      "latitude": "40.7903",
      "longitude": "-73.9597"
    }
  }
  }
  $scope.marker = {
    id: 6,
    "coords": {
      "latitude": "45.5200",
      "longitude": "-122.6819"
    }
  }
  $scope.map = {
    center: {
      latitude: 39.8282,
      longitude: -98.5795
    },
    zoom: 4
  };
});
```

Comment: Done, I just moved the button inside the map div and it worked, thank you Pratik!

Comment: I was calling the controller with a route provider and then again on the HTML, that's why it was showing the console.log twice, that was why the marker wasn't mooving too, I just erase the 'ng-controller="MapCtrl"' and solved the problem. Thanks again for helping me see it.